# Getting iPython for python3.5 in Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, ipython, python-3.5

I have recently been forced to use python3.5 for a project, which is fine as it installs smoothly from the `apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes`. The only problem is I don't know how to install iPython for it now.

I proceeded with `sudo python3.5 -m pip install ipython`, which seemed to come through smoothly, but now neither `python3.5` nor `python3.5 ipython` neither `python3.5 -i -c "import Ipython#or ipython"` shown any sign of it being available.

Comment: Does `which ipython3` give anything useful?

Comment: You should use `jupyter`. If you have `pip3` (which should point to your python3 installation), you can install `jupyter` with `pip3 install jupyter[all]`. Then you can install the `ipython` kernel with `python3.5 -m pip install ipykernel` and `python3.5 -m ipykernel install --user`.